# Set value of DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to set value of drop down list, using variable from code behind?

```
<asp:DropDownList  runat="server"                    
    <asp:ListItem Text="SomeText" Value='<%: valudeCodeBehind %>'></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and I put calculate string in code behind, lets say it is  `valudeCodeBehind ="113";`

But I am getting `<%: valudeCodeBehind %>` this value instead of 113. So how to pass it.

edit: `Value="<%= valudeCodeBehind %>"` doesnt work either. And it is not a typo (someone put that in comments)..

Comment: "<%= valudeCodeBehind %>"

Comment: I think its <%= variable %>

Comment: You also may have typo'd "value" -> valudeCodeBehind .. is that supposed to be "valueCodeBehind"?

Comment: How are you setting the DataSource of your Drop Down List?

Answer (score 3):

if you're already using codebehind to calculate values why not use something like

```
IdOfDDL.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("someText", valudeCodeBhind))
```

in your codebehind without messing with <% %> and keep your view clean.

Answer (score 0):

Or calling the method like this...

**CodeBehind**

```
public DataTable GetString()
{
    //... do what you have to do here
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlString" DataSource='<%# GetString() %>'
 DataTextField="MyString"  DataValueField="StringID" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The Codebehind method should be public to access from ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You may want to try expression builder. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/The-CodeExpressionBuilder) is a good article about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList  runat="server"                    
    <asp:ListItem Text="SomeText" Value='<% FunctionFromCodeBehind(); %>'>
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And code behind:

```
private Int32 FunctionFromCodeBehind()
{
    int result = 0;
    //calculations here
    return result;
}
```